# Segmentation fault(core dump) when trying to call my deleteStudent function

Tags: c

I try to make a program about student registration.

This is my header file:

```
#ifndef STUDENTREGISTRATION_H_
#define STUDENTREGISTRATION_H_
typedef struct {
char name[30];
char surname[30];
char faculty[30];
char department[30];
int age;
int grade;
int count;
} STUDENT_STRUCT, *STUDENT;

STUDENT_STRUCT students[100];
STUDENT_STRUCT empty;
void *data_init();
void *data_set(STUDENT s);
void addStudent(int count,STUDENT s);
void displayList(int count);
void free_list(STUDENT s);
void deleteStudent(int index,int count);
void Choice();


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "string.h"
#include "StudentREGISTRATION.h"

void *data_set(STUDENT s) {

s = students;
return s;
}
void addStudent(int count,STUDENT s) {

printf("Please enter an information about student:\n");
printf("Name:");
scanf("%s", s->name);
printf("Surname:");
scanf("%s", s->surname);
printf("Faculty:");
scanf("%s", s->faculty);
printf("Department:");
scanf("%s", s->department);
printf("Age:");
scanf("%d", &s->age);
printf("Grade:");
scanf("%d", &s->grade);
students[count].age = s->age;
students[count].grade=s->grade;
strcpy(students[count].department,s->department);
strcpy(students[count].faculty,s->faculty);
strcpy(students[count].name,s->name);
strcpy(students[count].surname, s->surname);
free_list(s);
}

void displayList(int count) {
int i;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if(students[i].name[0] != "\0" && students[i].surname[0] != "\0" && students[i].faculty[0] !=        "\0" && students[i].department[0] !="\0"&&students[i].age != 0 && students[i].grade != 0)
    {
        printf("%d.) %s %s %s %s %d %d \n", i + 1, students[i].name,
        students[i].surname, students[i].faculty,
        students[i].department, students[i].grade, students[i].age);
    }

}
}
void free_list(STUDENT s) {

free(s);
}
void deleteStudent(int index,int count) {
int i;
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    if(index-1==i)
    {
        students[i].name[0]="\0";
        students[i].surname[0]="\0";
        students[i].department[0]="\0";
        students[i].faculty[0]="\0";
        students[i].age=0;
        students[i].grade=0;
    }
}
 displayList(count);
}
 void *data_init()
{
STUDENT s=(STUDENT)malloc(sizeof(STUDENT_STRUCT));
return s;
}
void Choice() {
STUDENT s;
int a=0;
printf("Enter your choice to do with a program\n");
printf("Press A for adding student\n");
printf("Press L to display a student list\n");
printf("Press D for deleting student\n");
printf("Press E for exit\n");
char choice = ' ';
int index;
while (choice != 'E') {

    printf("Your choice:");
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    switch (choice) {
    case 'A':
        s=data_init(s);
        addStudent(a,s);
        a++;
        break;
    case 'L':

        displayList(a);
        break;
    case 'D':
        printf("Enter an index:");
        scanf("%d ",index);
        deleteStudent(index,a);
        break;
    }
}

exit(1);
}
```

I got segmentation fault(code dump) error, when program try to run delete function in switch case. Where is my fault in this code, i guess its all about pointer. But i try to allocate and deallocate for each member of students. Where is the problem, if there is someone to tell me, i'll appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: And also, my main() called Choice() function to run a program. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @user3121023 This should be an Answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'd first try checking that the index is between 0 and count before doing anything else. That could be causing the error right there. Also, you don't seem to close the #ifndef in the header file with #endif.

Also as someone pointed out, scanf should give an address instead of a variable. ex:

```
scanf("%d ", &z);
```

Comment: Edited: i don't get segmentation fault anymore after applied these steps but program stuck in delete() i can't get any output

Comment: At this point, I'd throw a couple printf()s in there to see where the problem is arising. Is it in the loop in delete? Does it ever find the correct element? does the loop exit? Is the problem in displayList() with an item that is "deleted" (zeroed out might be more appropriate)